# Sub menu on scrollable parent using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, scrollable

I am programming this on rails but the problem is in html+css+javascript.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Menu1
    <ul style="overflow: hidden auto; height: 400px; display: none;">
      <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#">
          <div>submenu1</div>
        </a>
        <ul style="left: 258px; height: 400px; display: none;">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>Subsubmenu1</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="line"></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div>Subsubmenu2</div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have this long list of submenus so i want it scrollable. 
As soon as i add overflow to the sub menu list the Sub Sub menus stop being displayed. I tried checking for javascript errors without success.

Comment: Can you include your CSS and Javascript into the snippet?

Comment: The question was rather general. Is it possible or not to have sub submenus on scrollable submenus? I added the code to illustrate. I think it is obvious I am not really good at frontend solutions so it would be difficult to find the relevant pieces of CSS and JS.

Comment: Your code above is not very helpful. Why are you using `display none` & `left` CSS. Does it display when you remove the `display: none;` style.

Comment: I am aware the piece of code is not helpful. As I stated previously I dont want a specific solution for this piece of code. I am asking a generic question whether it is possible to have a submenu(show on hover) on a scrollable parent.